# Can not find a book about how ruby works inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, interpreter

I love ruby, it's a beautiful and elegant language!

I have learn ruby core and language basics,
Now I want to find some deeper information about this language.

Does anyone know books about:

- how ruby interpreter works
- how ruby works with memory
- other interesting info

Please, advise me a good ruby-literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Ruby Under a Microscope](http://nostarch.com/rum), it should provide you enough details you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Not actually a book, but couple of slide decks to get you started:

http://www.slideshare.net/burkelibbey/ruby-internals

http://www.slideshare.net/nirusuma/what-lies-beneath-the-beautiful-code

Answer (score 0):

In addition to presents answers, I found this slide deck:

http://www.slideshare.net/vasfed/ss-15765868?fb_action_ids=231042317044533&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=aggregation&fb_aggregation_id=288381481237582

Maybe it will helps someone like me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is online blog looks like a book "Ruby under a microscope"http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope